# No gluon interaction between nucleons

Tags: nuclear-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, pions, gluons

Given the spatial overlap of nucleon wave functions within the nucleus, why is the bonding of nucleons only the result of pion exchange and not of gluon interactions between quarks in different nucleons?

Comment: The reason lies here http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/exchg.html . it ois not simple, has to do with quantum mechanics and the range of the colored force, among other stuff.

Comment: There's glue in the exchange pions too.

Comment: Gluons can be exchanged between color singlets.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers

Answer (score 5):

Long-range nucleon-nucleon interactions are dominated by pion exchange, but at short enough distances the quark-gluon structure of the nucleons is important.

As shown in this [plot from Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/98/Nucleonic_potential.png), one-pion exchange dominates for nucleon-nucleon separation more than a couple of fermis. As the nucleons get closer, two-pion and heavier meson exchanges become important, until at distances less than a fermi, the nucleons repel each other because of the net effect of quark and [gluon exchange](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.11430), vector meson exchange, and the Pauli exclusion principle, but [the details are not yet completely understood](https://doi.org/10.3389/fphy.2019.00233).

[image: Nucleon-nucleon exchange potential vs distance]